# How to wake up a thread being blocked by select.poll.poll() function from another thread in socket programming in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I have no way to wake up a thread being blocked by poll.poll() function . Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 8):

The way to handle this is to have an extra file descriptor included in the list of descriptors passed to poll().  For that descriptor wait for a read to be ready.  Have any other thread which wants to awaken the thread waiting on poll() *write* to that extra descriptor.  At that point, the thread which called poll() resumes execution, sees that the extra descriptor is that which awakened it, and does whatever.

The normal way to get this extra file descriptor initially is to open an unnamed pipe with pipe().  That way you have two descriptors: the one you hand the read wait in poll() on and the other which you write to to awaken the thread waiting on poll().

Comment: Wouldn't `eventfd()` be even easier to use than `pipe()`?

Comment: opensource portable implementation of this strategy in case it helps anyone:    https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/v2.1-Dev/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Execution/WaitForIOReady.cpp#L126    and   https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/v2.1-Dev/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Execution/UpdatableWaitForIOReady.h#L30

Answer (score 7):

There are many legitimate reasons to want to wake up a blocking poll(2) or select(2) before it times out. Any time you need to add or remove a socket from the fd list being polled, you need to break out of the wait. If you rely on the timeout, the timeout has to be short to be responsive, but short timeouts can result in a lot of needless thrashing.

For Linux anyway, you can use [eventfd(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd) to create a file descriptor to add to your fd list. When you need to break out of the wait, write to the eventfd.

Answer (score -1):

Use a timeout in your poll call, so it doesn't block indefinitely. N.B.: the timeout value is in milliseconds.

Comment: Because of my goal,so I cant use timeout in my circumstance. Do you have another way ? I just want to wake up this blocked thread from another thread

Comment: The only way to break into a blocking system call like `poll` is to use a signal. But that is a bit like using a sledgehammer to open an egg; it works but it can be very messy. *Why* do you think you cannot use a timeout?

Comment: My Application has 1000 poll to run in parallel, the poll that have no coming event will be blocked, anytime if poll receives a event, it have to unblock immediately to handle this event. If i set time out too long, the event handled lately, otherwise, if i set time out too short , 1000 poll will hold all operating time of CPU. That is reason I cant set timeout for poll().

Comment: As soon as one of the polled file descriptors has data available, `poll` will return. So why would you need to unblock it?

Comment: I'm building an Server that each poll will be added a file descriptor from another thread, its self cant add a file descriptor, at the time, this poll is blocking and it's added a file descriptor from another thread, the file descriptor will not be handled until the poll is out of timeout. Its my problem.

Comment: In that case I'd say you need to re-think the architecture of your application. Maybe you can split the single application that handles 1000 file descriptors up into 10 processes that handle 100 file descriptors each (using `multiprocessing`).

Comment: Thank you for your help so much. I'll re-think the architecture of my application